# Display data category wise

Tags: php

We have six categories Example :- a,b,c,d,e,f.

In each category we have products.

In a category i have 2 products & in b category i have 1 product.

I'm fetching this data from database.

```
product_id category_id
1                1
2                1
3                2
```

What should be best logic to display records, so two categories not display next to it.

Output product id like :- 1,3,2

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Use joins and group by

Comment: so you want to group them?

Comment: Yes need to group them but if i'm going to group by category_id then it's going to display only 1 product. Then what can i do?. I need all products

Answer (score 0):

I do not think such function exists. Even if you use `DISTINCT` it will only select the ones that do not duplicate and leave the out the rest, which is not what you need. So, I think I would run two queries at the same time, the first one will choose all the distinct queries, like 1,2,3,4 and after that, you can create a second query just to query normally all products. This way, let say.. if you had products by type like `1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,` then, the first sql query would list `1,2,3,4,5` and the second will just query normally, but still, your clients will see the distinct ones first.

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM table ORDER by id
```